# Change value of Object Variable through a vector

Tags: c++, class, variables

I'm developing a simulation game in cpp using Visual Studio 2017 for School and in the development phase I got stuck in this situation.
So, what I did was create a new project to try and recreate that issue in the simplest form, so that it would be easier to debug.

Below is the main file and all the associated source codes:

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Car.h"

int main() {

    Vehicle v;

    v.addCar(1);
    v.addCar(2);
    v.addCar(3);


    cout << v.getCars()[1].id << endl;
    v.getCars()[1].id = 99;
    cout << v.getCars()[1].id << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef CLUSTE2R_H
#define CLUSTE2R_H
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;  
#endif
```

Car.h

```
#ifndef CLUSTE1R_H
#define CLUSTE1R_H
#pragma once
#include "Vehicle.h"

using namespace std;


class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    int id;
    Car(int id);
    ~Car();
};

#endif
```

Car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"

Car::Car(int id)
{
    this->id = id;
}


Car::~Car()
{
}
```

Vehicle.h

```
#ifndef CLUSTER_H
#define CLUSTER_H
#pragma once

#include <vector>
//#include "Car.h"

class Car;
using namespace std;


class Vehicle
{
private:
    vector<Car> cars;

public:
    Vehicle();
    ~Vehicle();

    vector<Car> getCars();
    void addCar(int id);

};

#endif
```

Vehicle.cpp

```
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
//class Car;
Vehicle::Vehicle()
{
}


Vehicle::~Vehicle()
{
}


vector<Car> Vehicle::getCars()
{
    return this->cars;
}

void Vehicle::addCar(int id)
{
    Car c(id);

    cars.reserve(cars.size() + 1);
    cars.push_back(c);
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to get the following output:

> 2 \n 99

This is what I'm getting:

> 2 \n 2

What am I doing wrong? I believe the issue is associated with the main.cpp file. But I'm not quite sure how to achieve what I want in any other way...

Comment: When you call `getCars()`, a copy of the vector is made. You're only mutating the copy of it.

Comment: Does it make sense for a car to store cars?

Comment: So, how could I do what I need?

Comment: How am I storing cars in a car?

Comment: Modify it as `vector<Car> &getCars();`. But then having the vector as private makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, that solves it. And you're right. Then making it private is useless. Is there a more elegant way of approaching this?

Comment: @AntónioFaneca approaching what? currently your code looks like you better use just a `std::vector<Car>` instead of `Vehicle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are returning a new instance of a vector when you call `getCars()` function from your Vehicle, this means that all changes to the vector will not be applied to the original vector in the class.

To fix this you could just return a reference  of the vector(changing the `vector<Car> getCars();` to `std::vector<Car>& getCars()`).

You could also make a local copy of the vector and then setting the vector to the class.

Comment: Thank you very much. That single change solved it for me. And it makes a lot of sense. I'm not making that mistake again. thanks!

Comment: returning a non-const reference is as good as making the member public

Comment: as @PythEh mentioned in a comment, doing this would not make sense having it as a private member data. It would also destroy the Data encapsulation of the class. You could as well create a `void editCar(int index, int value);` function in your class that will directly edit the vector without exposing it to the public, thus keeping it private and encapsulated in the class.